# The type UserDBContext cannot be used as a type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type of method 'AddApiAuthorization<TUser, TContext>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to set up Authorization using Identity for my React ASP.NET Core app. I'm following the ASP.NET Core docs: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

In the previous examples I'm using my 'UserDBContext' wherever 'ApplicationContext' is referenced in the docs without trouble but in this particular instance I'm getting an error.

I'm running into an error when I try to configure the 'AddIdentityServer' service. In my Startup.cs

Full Error:

`The type 'projectName.UserDBContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.AddApiAuthorization<TUser, TContext>(IIdentityServerBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'projectName.UserDBContext' to 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Interfaces.IPersistedGrantDbContext'`

User.cs:

```
namespace project {

    public class User : IdentityUser {

        [DataType (DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime created { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string lastname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range (1, 100)]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength (100)]
        public string password { get; set; }

    }

    public class UserDBContext : IdentityDbContext {

        public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }

        public UserDBContext (DbContextOptions<UserDBContext> options) : base (options) { }

    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {

            services.AddControllersWithViews ();

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles (configuration => {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            services.AddDbContext<UserDBContext> (options =>
                options.UseNpgsql (Configuration.GetConnectionString ("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User> ()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDBContext> ();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<User, UserDBContext>();


            services.AddAuthentication ()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt ();

        }
```

This is the code that is giving me the error:

```
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<User, UserDBContext>();
```

Comment: The error is telling you that your `UserDBContext` class does not satisfy the type constraint placed on the `TContext` type parameter and that, in order to satisfy said constraint, `UserDBContext` must implement `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Interfaces.IPersistedGrantDbContext`.

Comment: I understand that but looking at the API its looking for a TContext and I'm giving it a 'TContext' because its looking for same type in previous lines of code according to docs and it works, I'ts just not working for this particular method and I'm not sure why

Comment: It has nothing whatsoever to do with the other methods that you're calling. The type parameter is declared and constrained by that method. See the documentation: [AddApiAuthorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityserverbuilderconfigurationextensions.addapiauthorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
public class UserDBContext : IdentityDbContext,IPersistedGrantDbContext {

    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }

    public UserDBContext (DbContextOptions<UserDBContext> options) : base (options) { }

}
```